# Regular Expression on a non required field

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a field that isn't required but I still want to add a regular expression to it.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
            "regex",
            function (value, element, regexp) {
                var check = false;
                var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
            },
            "Please check your input."
        );


        $(".numeric").rules("add", { number: true });

    });

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseAmount, new { @class = "currency numeric", Value = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Model.PurchaseAmount), style = "width:160px" })
```

Because the field isn't required it wont work. Any ideas that would help?

Comment: Why don't you make your regular expression: be \s*|(your wanted regular expression) ?

Comment: I don't want to sound like a newb but I know im going to haha. be \s*|(your wanted regular expression)? I used this javascript method. How would I implement the way you speak of?

Comment: I understand this portion of it (your wanted regular expression). I don't want an answer I just want an example of how I may be able to apply if to this textboxfor

Comment: Just use that regular expression instead of the original.  It essentially means "an empty string or a string that matches your regular expression".  The | means or, \s* means any empty space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your regular expression: be \s*|(your wanted regular expression). Which, as Tuskan360 says, means "an empty string or a string that matches your regular expression"

Should have added this as answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as your regular expression **\^$|(your wanted regular expression)**.